# Android string resource with a number

Tags: java, android, string, resources

Im having an issue when using `getIdentifier(resourceName, "string", packageName)`. My string resources name is dynamic and is combined of a prefix, which is "number_" and a postfix, which is a number e.g "5". The final string name looks like this "number_5". The problem is when im using the getIdentifier method it still returns a resId, as if this resource would exists in my locale, but i don't have it in my current locale, it's in another one.

I've tried to clean my project and i tried to use `getIdentifier(packageName + ":string/" + resourceName, null, null))` and also

```
public static int getResId(String variableName, Class<?> c) {
    try {
        Field idField = c.getDeclaredField(variableName);
        return idField.getInt(idField);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return -1;
    } 
}
```

The context of current locale is correct, i've checked it by:

```
c.getResources().getConfiguration().locale
```

Why does getIdentifier return a valid resource id from another non-default string resources?

Answer (score 1):

It returns a valid identifier because there is one: your `R` class contains the identifier. How this identifier is resolved when you load the resource is a completely different matter. Please note that you should always provide all the strings in the default folder (`res/values`) to avoid runtime errors.